# XMLHttpRequest state never goes to DONE

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, model-view-controller

I got this mvc core application. One of its methods looks like this(for now)

```
    public IActionResult Call(string call)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        return Ok (call);
    }
```

and a javascript in browser looks like that

```
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.withCredentials = true;
        xhttp.open("GET", request, true);
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4)
            {
                if (this.status == 200)
                {
                    SetAnswerText(this.responseText);
                }
                else
                {
                    SetApiCallTextAreaValue("request - \n" + request + "\n failed; status = " + this.status);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                SetApiCallTextAreaValue("current status is " + this.readyState + "\n" + this.responseText);
            }
        }
```

for some reason, I get only notification with readystate==3(LOADING), and never.. with readystate==4(DONE) which im expecting.

Can you help me figuring it out why thats happaning?

btw, if I open an url to this Call method in browser like https://..../Call/?call=123 it works absoulutely fine..

Comment: If your issue was a basic typo, you should delete your question as it is too narrow to be helpful to other users.

Comment: You should add the other events (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)) in order to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

omg.. forgot to change function name from SetAnswerText to SetApiCallTextAreaValue..
have to sleep more..
found a error only when I looked at code in browser :P